# AWS EC2 KDE Desktop Graphical Lag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, lag, kde-plasma

I am attempting to use KDE as a gateway server for my environment to support 6-10 users. I have installed KDE with XRDP on a EC2 Redhat 7.4 m4.2xlarge instance. The server has significant graphics lag, with windows stuttering when dragged across the screen, not affected by number of users.

KDE Version: 
KDE Development Platform: 4.14.8
Plasma Desktop Shell: 4.11.19

Graphics (Default): 
direct rendering: Yes
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.9, 256 bits)
    GL_ARB_conditional_render_inverted, GL_ARB_conservative_depth, 
    GL_NV_conditional_render, GL_NV_depth_clamp, GL_NV_fog_distance, 
    GL_OES_element_index_uint, GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap, 
VGA compatible controller: Cirrus Logic GD 5446

I am wondering if potentially I need to switch to a different instance type or install updated graphics drivers ?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need the UI?  Are you running a tool that is a GUI only?

Comment: The developers require a GUI for their applications, the goal was to move off windows servers we were using.

Comment: I recently tired to spin up a new instance off my AMI and installed Gnome. It had the same graphical lag.